# Modifying recaptcha table width

Tags: css, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate recaptcha on a contact form on my site but cannot get the width of the table to change, it is rendering at 692px whereas I have everything else set to a width of 320px. I was able to set the width of the recaptcha img but I cannot alter the table width.

This is the css I am using:

```
table#recaptcha_table.recaptchatable.recaptcha_theme_white {
    width: 50% !important;
}

#recaptcha_widget_div {
    width: 320px !important;
}

.recaptcha-div {
    width:320px;
}
```

Comment: What's the HTML? We'll need that to give you a proper answer.

Comment: or you can post your code sample on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
transform: scale(0.8);
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This link has the information you need.
http://www.ehow.com/how_12218694_make-recaptcha-smaller.html

Keep in mind that the minimum width will be 300px because of the captcha image supplied by google. However, if 300 is still too big, you can try this clever hack for adjusting the width smaller then 300, then popping out larger on hover.  Not ideal, but it does work.  Best of luck.
http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2011/03/make-recaptcha-smaller.html

Answer (score 1):

I also used recaptcha in my project and faced the same issue on the width of the recaptcha. i fixed this by using the below CSS.

> style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0
>   0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"

I think this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.g-recaptcha {
    display: block;
    max-width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to describe how this solves the problem? Code-only answers are discouraged. Thanks!